# Show scrollbar permanently on react-select

Tags: react-select

Currently, my react-select component only shows the scrollbar right after opening it and when scrolling, otherwise it disappears. Is there a way to show it all the time (providing there are enough options to justify it at all)? I am using it with bootstrap 4 if that makes any difference.